# what is the equivalent in java of dictionary from.net?

Tags: java, json

i'm writing a java client for .net server which uses REST/JSON interface. one of the APIs expects a class with a dictionary inside it. i tried to use a hashmap in the java client but seems that the serialization to json is different for java's hashmap and .net dictionary? i'm using gson by the way. is there another object i should use in java? is there a workaround besides coding the serialization myself?

Comment: Can you show what you expect and what you get when serializing Java, and what your data class in Java looks like. That may help.

Answer (score 0):

Most people would use `HashMap<String, String>`, or, for some json purposes, `HashMap<String, Object>`. The Jackson open source library for parsing JSON in Java will happily deliver these (declared via the interface `Map<String, something>` where 'something' depends on which Jackson API you use.

Comment: i used HashMap, but the json output was different from what c# expected when using dictionary.

Comment: @Sophie: Show your C# output and your Java output (and say which libraries you are using). Add this to the question (there is an edit button).